# Classes for the ISO 01.140.30 Documents in administration, commerce and industry family

Tags: document-classes, iso

Are there any classes that implement the requirements of ISO 6422, ISO 8439, or similar national (doesn't matter which or whose) or international standards for *commercial and administrative* paperwork?

Answer (score 2):

There is the `isov2` class which catered for ISO standards in 2002. I don't know if ISO have made any changes to their requirements since then. If they have it should not be too difficult to use `isov2` as a basis followed by some `\renewcommand{....` to get updated output.

Comment: Unfortunately, `iso` for standards themselves, not for commercial documents described in ISO 6422, ISO 8439, etc.